# why does "ClassType Object;" equals to "ClassType(Object);" in C++?

Tags: c++

in first, want to start to mention that it could be sorry for my bad english.

in C++, when we want to create a instance of certain type of class, we usually use "ClassType ObjectName;"

for example,

```
class Foo {};
Foo instance1;
```

but, i've met some codes make me embarassment a little. it following next.

```
class A {/*....bla bla*/};
class B {
    public:
        B(char*) {}
};

void main() {
    A aaa;
    B(aaa); // this makes a error.
}
```

by trial and error, i could know that "`B(aaa);`" is exactly same to "`B aaa;`".
But why? is this a kind of what depicted on standard documents? if so, please let me know where i can see.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
    Thank you for your all replies. 
    But i think that i've omitted some codes. Sorry.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{

};
class B
{
public:
    B() { cout << "null\n";  }
    B(char* str) {} 
    void print() {
        cout << "print!\n";
    }
};

void main()
{
    A aaa;
    //B(aaa); this line makes a error that says 'redefinition; different basic types'. VS2008
    B(aa1);
    aa1.print();
}
```

Output:

```
null
print!
```

as you can see, "B(aa1)" statement means not to pass aa1 to constructor as argument, but to create a instance aa1.

Until now, I've known "B(argument)" to "Pass argument to propel one of a overloaded construtor, and create a nameless temporary instance".
but value "aa1" looks lke neither a defined value nor a temporary instance.

Comment: They're completely different `B(aaa)` is trying to call your `B` constructor and pass class `A` as the args but this is not defined hence the error, `B aaa` declares an instance of class `B` named `aaa`

Comment: @EdChum No, `B(aaa);` is a declaration.

Comment: @T.C. ah yes [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) that old nugget pops up again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes a set of parenthesis is **needed** to disambiguate declarations.

For example:

```
int *f();     // a function returning a pointer to int
int (*f)();   // a pointer to a function returning an int
```

Rather than listing exactly when and where using parenthesis is required and where it perhaps should be forbidden (because it is useless), the standard just says that they are allowed.

So you end up with the slightly confusing:

```
int   a;     // an int variable
int   (b);   // another int variable
```